# Why does break work in switch blocks but not if-else blocks in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, break

Just beginning with C and noticed this detail. Not a pressing question, just curious.

I tried searching for the answer but couldn't seem to find an explanation.

(not sure what else to say, this sentence is just to satisfy the 220-character requirement)

Comment: If the `break` were able to terminate an `if` clause, it would be impossible to use it to terminate a loop or a switch case, such as with `if(condition) { break; }`. Without being inside a conditional, the loop would not loop, and the case code would not run to completion.

Comment: It's not great to circumvent posting requirements by adding noise to your post. A better idea would be to include a statement of your actual question in the body of the question instead of relying on the title being the only statement of your question. This also gives you opportunities to create a more succinct title and a  more refined question statement. Remember that these posts are not only for the asker, but for future readers.

Answer (score 4):

A break that only exited an `if` statement would not be useful. Consider this code:

```
if (test)
{
    A;
    break;
    B;
}
```

Since the `break` exits the `if` statement, this is equivalent to:

```
if (test)
{
    A;
}
```

So why write the `break;` and the code after it at all? To be useful here, the break would need to be conditional; it would have to be something like:

```
if (test)
{
    A;
    if (want to exit)
        break;
    B;
}
```

But now the `break` is inside another `if`, so it would only exit that `if`, not the outer one. So it cannot do the job of exiting the outer `if`.

Also, if `break` exited an `if` statement, rather than a containing loop or `switch`, then it would not be useful in loop statements.

`break` is used in loops (`for`, `while`, and `do`) to exit loops when some condition is reached. For this use, the `break` statement must be inside an `if`. For example, a loop for searching for some element in an array would have a form like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    if (array[i] matches conditions)
        break;
```

Given that a useful `break` in a `for` loop must be inside an `if` statement, a `break` that terminated an `if` statement would not be useful. If the `break` above only exited the `if` statement, it would not be useful, and the `for` loop would continue exiting even though we want it stopped.

If you do have a need to exit an `if` statement, you can do it with `goto`:

```
if (test)
{
    A;
    if (error occurs)
        goto EndOfIf:
    B;
}
EndOfIf:
```

or with an enclosing loop or `switch`:

```
switch (0)
{
    default:
    if (test)
    {
        A;
        if (error occurs)
            break;
        B;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The break statement works differently in switch blocks and if-else blocks in the C programming language because they are designed to serve different purposes and are structured differently.

Break statement is used to exit a switch block early, while if-else blocks do not have this behaviour since they don't have the concept of "fall-through" like switch blocks. Instead, the program continues executing through the if-else chain, evaluating each condition and executing the corresponding block until one condition evaluates to true or none of the conditions match.

```
switch (value) {
case 1:
    // Do something if value is 1
    break; // Exit the switch block after handling case 1
case 2:
    // Do something if value is 2
    break;
// ... other cases
default:
    // Do something if none of the cases match
}
```